# Petición get por nombre de usuario rest api nodejs

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express

Estoy haciendo una rest API con nodejs express y mysql, digamos que tengo una tabla que se llama 'integrantes' (de un grupo de música), que tiene id, nombre e instrumento. He conseguido hacer get por id, pero se puede hacer por el nombre de integrante? He probado a hacerlo pero no me devuelve nada.

Tengo esto:

```
// Por ID
router.get('/integrantes/:id', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM  integrante WHERE id = ?', [id], (err, rows, fields) => {
        if(!err) {
            res.json(rows[0]);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});

// Por Nombre
router.get('/integrantes/:nombre', (req, res) => {
    const { nombre } = req.params;
    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM  integrante WHERE nombre = ?', [nombre], (err, rows, 
    fields) => {
        if(!err) {
            res.json(rows[0]);
        } else {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express no va a ser capaz con la declaración que has puesto de distinguir un nombre de un id, ya que ambos cumplen el mismo patrón (la única diferencia es el nombre que le has puesto a la variable).

Puedes hacer algo como:

```javascript
// Por ID
router.get('/integrantes/:id', (req, res) => { ... }
```

y

```javascript
// Por Nombre: /integrantes?nombre=Rob
router.get('/integrantes', (req, res) => {
  const nombre = req.query.nombre;
  ...
});
```

Comment: Osea si quisiera hacer el get con el nombre, borro el get de la id y ya esta, y si quiero utilizar las dos, lo haría como tu dices. Gracias